# Cloud ML Hyper Parameter Tuning for CATEGORICAL parameter pass integer value

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Recently, when I submit training jobs with Hyper Parameter Tuning for CATEGORICAL parameter, Cloud ML pass the options with integer values instead of selections from `categoricalValues` parameter described in documentation [https://cloud.google.com/ml/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.jobs#parameterspec].

Before 12 Jan 2017 (in JST), Cloud ML did pass the option with values selected from `categoricalValues`. The current behavior seems begin at around 13 JAN 2017, on my projects.

Is it the regression of Cloud ML Hyper Parameter Tuning, or the change of feature?
I cannot assure that the documentation doesn't match with current behavior (It's ambiguous I think). Anyway the behavior was clearly changed and I have to deal with it if it is the permanent feature change.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.  I will post an update here when it is fixed.

Update: Thank you for reporting the problem.  This should now be fixed.